# I am trying to build spark, on Mac and the following error occurs

Tags: maven, build, open-source

When I run the command

./build/mvn -DskipTests clean package

the following error occurs(though it seems that the java home environment was not set properly)

[WARNING] javac exited with exit code -1
[ERROR] ## Exception when compiling 10 sources to /Users/johnding/spark/common/tags/target/scala-2.12/classes
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/javac" (in directory "/Users/johnding/spark"): error=2, No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

> though it seems that the java home environment was not set properly

Make sure you set JAVA_HOME properly.

Use `echo $JAVA_HOME` to check.

On Mac you can use jenv to manage your java version.

(Don't forget to restart your terminal application or resource your configuration.)